# how to get and parse value from <label> tag in php code?

Tags: php, database, get, label

currently i have problem with this  tag. 
I cannot get the value for this label to store in my database.

```
<label class="autopopulate4" size="5" for="totalscore" id="totalscore" name="totalscore">100</label>
```

The above code is the label tag.

Can anybody help me to solve this problem ?

How to get and parse the updated value into database ?

Do i have other alternative to make this happen ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you have to use ajax and javascript to get and send also php to update

Comment: You either need to use AJAX, or preferably a `<form>` element to actually send the variable to the back-end. Then you need to use `$_POST['totalscore']` based on the `name` attribute from the form element. Check out the [**basics of PHP forms**](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) for more info.

Comment: why not .html()?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending data at server side using Ajax then you can get label value in J's variable using below jQuery and then pass it in Ajax parameters to send server side.

Var labelval = $('#totalscore').html();